# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library while adding ActionBarSherlock to my project

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to add ActionBarSherlock to an existing Android project. I followed the steps in the video below:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html

I added the *library* folder from the ZIP in Eclipse and updated the compiler version and the Android Support Library. But when I add ActionBarSherlock to my project afterwards, I get the following error:

*The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\Workspaces\Android\Sherlock\library\bin\sherlockactionbar.jar'*

I don't understand why he goes looking for this jar, which obviously doesn't exist...

PS: My project name for ActionBarSherlock is SherlockActionBar here.

Thanks in advance.